# Remove zero entries from an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, zero

I have an array of values `x = {0,0,1,2,3,0,0,7,8}` and I want to remove the zero entries using C.

**Attempt:**

I am attempting to loop through each value in the array and check if the entry is not equal to zero. If this condition is true, then I am attempting to populate a new array with original array value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int x[] = { 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 7, 8 };
    int i;
    int x_upd[100];
    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        if (x[i] != 0) {
            x_upd[i] = x[i]; // if true, populate new array with value
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        printf(" Peak updated %d\t", x_upd[i]); //
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output is not giving me the values `{1,2,3,7,8}` as desired. Instead, I am getting garbage values at the location where the zeros used to be.

Any advice on what I am doing wrong here? Do I need an else statement?

Comment: `int i, j = 0;` ...`x_upd[j++] = x[i];`...`for(i=0;i<9;i++)` --> `for(i = 0; i < j; i++)`

Comment: In the second loop, where you print the values, what do you think you will print for elements of `x_upd` that are not initialized? You need to keep track of the new size as well.

Comment: This is something I still don't fully understand, but would I be printing some reference to the variable address?

Comment: "I am getting garbage values at the location where the zeros used to be." --> What value did you expect there in the uninitialized portion of `x_upd[]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is already such a function in C++. It is named `remove_copy`. In C such a function can look the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int * remove_copy(const int *in, size_t n, int *out, int value)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i != n; i++)
    {
        if (in[i] != value) *out++ = in[i];
    }

    return out;
}

int main( void )
{
    int a[] = { 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 7, 8 };
    int b[sizeof(a) / sizeof(*a)];
    const size_t N = sizeof(a) / sizeof(*a);

    int *last = remove_copy(a, N, b, 0);

    for (int *first = b; first != last; ++first)
    {
        printf("%d ", *first);
    }

    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 2 3 7 8
```

Or the function can return the number of the copied values

```
size_t remove_copy(const int *in, size_t n, int *out, int value)
{
    size_t m = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i != n; i++)
    {
        if (in[i] != value) out[m++] = in[i];
    }

    return m;
}
```

As for your code then you need to use an additional variable that will keep the index in the destination array. For example

```
int m = 0;

for ( i = 0; i < sizeof( x ) / sizeof( *x ); i++ )
{
    if ( x[i] != 0 )
    {
        x_upd[m++] = x[i]; // if true, populate new array with value
    }
}

for ( i = 0; i < m; i++ )
{
    printf(" Peak updated %d\t", x_upd[i] ); //
}
```

In fact the first loop corresponds to the second function implementation shown above.

Comment: There is one peculiar thing in the `remove_copy` - you can pass in the *same* pointer for both arguments and it will work in-place.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala It is wrong. Accordfing to the C++ the ranges shall not overlap.

Comment: The *C* version that you wrote. I do not care about C++ :D

Answer (score 3):

You should use separate counter variables, otherwise you will "skip" the indexes where the original array contains zeroes when assigning to the new array.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x[] = { 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 7, 8 };
    int i;
    int j = 0;
    int x_upd[100];
    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        if (x[i] != 0) {
            x_upd[j++] = x[i]; // if true, populate new array with value
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < j; i++) {
          printf(" Peak updated %d\t", x_upd[i]); //
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 2nd `i<9` --> `i<j`

Answer (score 3):

You go through the values 0-9 once, in order, and you skip values that are `0`, so you get `{garbage, garbage, 1, 2, 3, garbage, garbage, 7, 8}`. You'd have to keep a separate counter for the number of values that aren't `0`:

```
int position = 0;
for(i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
    if(x[i] != 0)
    {
        x_upd[position] = x[i]; // if true, populate new array with value
        position++;
    }
}

//loop until you get to counter
for(i = 0; i < position; i++)
{
    printf(" Peak updated %d\t", x_upd[i]); 
}
```

Comment: I think `position` makes more sense, but `counter` also conveys what I meant. Of course I forgot to change everything, edited now. _This was a response to an earlier comment_

Answer (score 2):

This problem can be solved by using **two indexes**: one for the *source array* (`x`) and another for the *destination array* (`x_upd`), which are `i` and `j`, respectively, in the code below.

```
int i, j;
for(i=0,j=0; i<9; i++) {
  if (!x[i]) // is x[i] zero?
     continue; // then skip this element

  // otherwise copy current element and update destination index
  x_upd[j++] = x[i];       
}
```

As you can see, the index `j` is only being *updated* (i.e.: incremented by one) when an element from `x` is being copied to `x_upd`, whereas the index `i` is being updated in each iteration of the `for` loop.

Answer (score 2):

This

```
for(i=0;i<9;i++)
{
  if(x[i] != 0)
  {
      x_upd[i] = x[i]; // if true, populate new array with value
  }
}
```

is skipping places in the `x_upd` array, since `i` is still being incremented even when you don't insert values in your new array.

You should do this:

```
int j = 0;
for(i=0;i<9;i++)
{
  if(x[i] != 0)
  {
      x_upd[j++] = x[i]; // if true, populate new array with value
  }
}
```

Then, here

```
for(i=0;i<9;i++)
{
  printf(" Peak updated %d\t",x_upd[i]); //
}
```

You should just count till `j`:

```
for(i=0;i<j;i++)
{
  printf(" Peak updated %d\t",x_upd[i]); //
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The trick in this situation, is to use a different variable to index into your other array.

So instead of this:

```
x_upd[i] = x[i];
```

You could have another variable `j` that only increments when you assign a value to `x_upd`

```
x_upd[j++] = x[i];
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to create a new array, see the working code with one array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int x[] = { 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 7, 8 };
    int i, n;

    for (i = 0, n = 0; i<9; i++)
    {
        if (x[i] != 0)
        {
            x[n++] = x[i];
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d,", x[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
1,2,3,7,8,
```

Comment: Maybe he needs to keep the original array.

Comment: He didn't explicitly say what does he need, with respect that he is the beginner i think he used second array just becouse he didnt know how to do it with one.

Answer (score 2):

You should increment x_upd array index separately. Something like:

```
int y = 0;
for(i=0;i<9;i++)
{
  if(x[i] != 0)
  {
      x_upd[y] = x[i]; // if true, populate new array with value
      y++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies here:

```
for(i=0;i<9;i++)
{
  if(x[i] != 0)
  {
      x_upd[i] = x[i]; // if true, populate new array with value
  }
}
```

and

```
for(i=0;i<9;i++) {
   printf(" Peak updated %d\t",x_upd[i]); //
}
```

You need to maintain separate index for x and x_upd, since they will be of different size(x_upd wont have the '0').

Try this:

```
int j;
for(i=0,j=0;i<9;i++) {
  if(x[i] != 0)
  {
      x_upd[j] = x[i]; // if true, populate new array with value
      j++;             // index for values inserted 

  }
}
```

and to print, use the correct count, obtained from the above code:

```
int k;
for(k=0;k<=j;k++) {
   printf(" Peak updated %d\t",x_upd[k]); //
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
int x[] = {0,0,1,2,3,0,0,7,8};
int i;
int count = 0;
int x_upd[100];
for(i=0;i<9;i++)
    {
      if(x[i] != 0)
      {
          x_upd[count] = x[i]; // if true, populate new array with value
          count++;
      }
    }

for(i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
      printf(" Peak updated %d\t",x_upd[i]); //
    }
return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
Peak updated 1  Peak updated 2  Peak updated 3  Peak updated 7  Peak updated 8
```

Answer (score 1):

no indexes needed

```
int populate(int *src, int *dest, int size)
//usage: - src - source table
//src - source table
//dest - destination table
//size of the source table - source table
//Return: -1 if pointers are null, -2 if source table has zero elements, or number of non zero elements copied
{
    int result = (src == NULL || dest == NULL) * -1;
    // it an equivalen of:
    // int result;    
    // if(src == NULL || dest == NULL)
    //     result = -1;
    // else
    //     result = 0;
    if(size == 0) result = -2;
    if (!result)
    {
        while(size--)
            if (*src)
            {
                *dest++ = *src;
                result++;
            }
        src++;
    }
    return result;
}



int main()
{
    int x[] = { 0,0,1,2,3,0,0,7,8 };
    int x_upd[100];

    int result = populate(x,x_upd, sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0]))
    for (int i = 0; i<result; i++)
    {
        printf(" Peak updated %d\t", x_upd[i]); //
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This `int result = (src == NULL || dest == NULL || size == 0) * -1;` does not suite well an ***educational** example*.

Comment: @alk I know what you mean - explained it in the comment :)

Comment: Usually I think you should put comments above the line you're commenting on. The function declaration looks disjointed if you put a comment between `int populate(int *src, int *dest, int size)` and `{`

Comment: Why not just return `0` when `size == 0`?  Why not simply write: `if (src == NULL || dest == NULL) return -1;`

Comment: @chqrlie I do not like functions with more than 1 return points for many reasons which I have explained here many times

Comment: @PeterJ: I suspected some such local coding rule.  The solution you have come up with to avoid a simple `return -1;` illustrates how counter-productive it can be ;-)

Comment: @chqrlie counter productive? Compile both. You probably did not code for the car or aviation industry :). Having more than one makes code review a real challenge (and you want to be paid :))

Comment: @PeterJ: I say *counter-productive* as it leads to unreadable code with questionable corner cases (such as why do you return -1 for size == 0). I am perfectly aware of the Misra-C coding conventions but I don't believe blind application of these rules lead to safer code. As a matter of fact, I have seen pretty bad code written for the car industry and worse even for security companies.  Do what you must to keep your job and get paid, but please take a break from this non-sense here on SO as you are contributing for free anyway ;-)

Comment: @chqrlie it is only your personal opinion, not the valid standard. I will definitely not change my coding style to your liking. So please do not say what is the non sense and what is not. This function returns -1 if size is zero because **_I_** decided that is invalid.

Comment: @PeterJ: indeed it is my personal opinion and experience regarding this specific Misra-C coding rule, no offense, I am just suggesting that it would make sense to return `0` for `size == 0`, conversely, passing a negative `size` should definitely be considered invalid.

Comment: @chqrlie I have right opposite opinion. If size == 0 is valid or invalid is in the coders discretion and program requirements. I can imagine results from the sensor - if no data received - it means something has gone wrong and some action from the program is needed

Comment: @PeterJ: it should really be part of program requirements, which in real life are always incomplete. I agree with you that lack of data from a sensor is a problem, but removing `0` values from an empty array does not seem to be open to interpretation. Returning 0 is consistent with similar situations in the C library: `memcpy(p, q, 0)` and `memset(p, c, 0)` do nothing successfully, `strstr("abc", "")` returns the first argument and `memcmp(p, q, 0)` returns `0`.

Comment: @chqrlie special amendment for you :). Zero is not good indicator as table may contain only zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

First, we must know the index of the "first non-zero" value in the array:

```
idx = 0;
while((idx < arrySize) & (arry[idx] == 0)) idx++;
```

and from here we can:

- Consider idx as "zero" in the subsequent loops involving the array, OR
- Constructing a new array holding only effective elements of the old array:

```
for ( j = 0; j < arrySize-idx; j++) newarry[j] = arry[j+idx];
```